# Android ListView with Checkbox: automatically unchecks

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listadapter

I've got a ListView with a custom BaseAdapter. The list items contain CheckBoxes that need to represent a property from a database.

I use CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener with a new OnCheckedChangeListener to detect changes, so I can change the database based on the current state of the CheckBox. Pretty straightforward stuff so far.

However, when scrolling further down the list, previously checked CheckBoxes get unchecked. I suspect this happens as soon as the views are recycled (I'm using the convertView/ViewHolder technique).

How can I stop this? What's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: To make things a bit clearer, the problem is that recycling views somehow calls OnCheckedChangeListener#onCheckedChanged(buttonView, isChecked) with isChecked == false.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that, by getting the checkbox using convertView.findViewById(), the onCheckedChangeListeners were still intact if the view was recycled. Calling checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) did the trick.

Comment: I was having the same problem when using checkbox in the child view of an ExpandableListView, and your trick worked for me as well. I had to put this in getChildView(..), where I check if we are recycling (i.e., convertView is not null), and set the OnCheckedChangeListener of the checkbox to null in that case. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but I dont know how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586442/listview-from-cursor-with-checkbox any ideas?

Comment: I know its an old thread but I have the same problem.It seems like the onCheckedChangeListener method is called randomly. What exactly do you mean by checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)? Its the null that confuses me! Have a look at my code if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444355/android-listview-with-checkbox-problem

Comment: I had the same issue as @SamikR, and this fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean array to store the checked state of each list item, record the changes inside `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`, then call `setChecked()` **after** `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`.