# android list view with cursor adapter scrolling issue

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-listview, android-contacts

in my app i load the contacts in a listview. i  have the listview with image,text and a checkbox and implemented by cursor adapter. my problem is when i scroll the listview up / down its position is changed. that is if choose(tick the checkbox) the position 1,3,4,2 and scroll down and up the ticked position is randomly changed. i have spend more time to find out the solution but i could not get it. please help me.

my code ex for adapter:

```
    public class ContactsListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    ContentResolver cr;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ContactsListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c,ArrayList<ContactPhoneInfo> selected) {
        super(context, c, true);
        this.checkedContacts = (ArrayList<ContactPhoneInfo>) selected.clone();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void bindView(View view,Context context_bind, Cursor cursor)
    {   
        final LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_linearLayout1);
        final TextView contactEntryText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_txtViewContactName);
        final CheckBox chkContact = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_chkContact);
        final TextView textCaption = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_layoutCaption);
        final ImageView photoView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_imgViewcontact);

        ContentResolver cr = context_bind.getContentResolver();
            .......

        int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        final String name = cursor.getString(1);

        contactEntryText.setText(name);
            .......
        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setFocusable(true);

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                chkContact.setChecked(!chkContact.isChecked());
            }
        });

        chkContact.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                .buttonView.........
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_listitem, parent,
                false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

the calling class coding:

```
        contactsListAdapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this,app.loadContactCursor(""),checkedContacts);
    setListAdapter(contactsListAdapter);
```

Comment: Why are you using a `CursorAdapter` instead of a `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: because i am fetching contacts and directly load the cursor in listview. i am not using arraylist. is there any way to load cursor by the arrayadapter?

Comment: Yes, you just access the data in the `getView` method of ArrayAdapter. The views are recycled to improve performance, so make sure keep that in mind.

Comment: thanks can you give example to this?

Comment: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications

Comment: if your data is from a Cursor I see no reason to use an ArrayAdapter.
I don't have such problems with something similar, the only difference I see is that I explicitly set Clickable and Focusable to false in the row's XML layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved my problem by call the **setOnCheckedChangeListener** method before calling **setChecked**

```
    chkContact.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            .buttonView.........
        }
    });
```

after that

```
chkContact.setChecked(!chkContact.isChecked());
```

i refer the following stack over flow question:

[Android listview with checkbox problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444355/android-listview-with-checkbox-problem)