# checkbox in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-cursoradapter

i read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566648/checkbox-listener-in-listview-with-cursoradapter?rq=1)

but i cant solve my problem . i using the CursorAdapter in listview.

i have a checkbox in the each item of list.if you checked the checkbox and the scrolling up and down . the checkbox will be disable.
i cant fix it . please help me.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_numer);

    tv1.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    tv2.setText(cursor.getString(3));

    final int pos = cursor.getPosition();

    final CheckBox repeatChkBx = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_check);

    String likes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("like"));

    if (likes.equals("yes")) {
        repeatChkBx.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        repeatChkBx.setChecked(false);
    }

    repeatChkBx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MyDatabase mydatabase = new MyDatabase(b);
            SQLiteDatabase mydb = mydatabase.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor.moveToPosition(pos);

            if (repeatChkBx.isChecked()) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("like", "yes");
                mydb.update("list", cv, "id ="+cursor.getString(1), null);
            } else {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("like", "no");
                mydb.update("list", cv, "id ="+cursor.getString(1), null);
            }
            mydb.close();
        }
    });

    }
```

i using an external database and like column for saving the favorite item.

Comment: why dont you use custom adapter it will be a much simpler and easy solution

Comment: he is using a custom adapter

Comment: is there any different between CustomAdapter and CursorAdapter?

Comment: CustomAdapter can solve this problem?

Comment: i think i have to us arrayadapter ....

Answer (score 2):

```
if (likes.equals("yes")) {
    repeatChkBx.setChecked(true);
} else {
    repeatChkBx.setChecked(false);
}
```

Here you set CheckBox mark time and again when a bindView called after your scrolling of a ListView. A user choice does not memorized and reset in the CheckBox. You need to memorized user choice of the CheckBox and set it in bindView.

Comment: so how can i memorized user choice in the bindView

Comment: Please use setOnItemClickListener for CursorAdapter and memorize position argument in the onItemClick(*, *, int position, *) callback.

Comment: You can also get Cursor on this callback by adapter.getItem(position) and memorize some Cursor identity value, for example database table row _id