# Android Studio, for Listview error working scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, mobile

for Android Studio with Java

Listview have not correctly scrollview, so mean I select first item in Listview but Selecting first item both another a item. So mean, showing  me two item, one's my selected item another random a item

What can I do about this situation

[image][image][image]

for Listview, selected item not correctly work

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Please post your listView Implementation.

Comment: XML or java? Which one?

Comment: Post Both code Implementation

Comment: you can fallow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274754/get-selected-item-from-single-selection-mode-listview-android

Comment: another way to select single selection in ListView set variable in Model class e.g isSelectItem by default it should be false when item select by using listener send call back to activity there in loop current position item isSelectItem set true rest of all set false and notify to adapter

Comment: @jcredking post my code

Comment: @AyazMuhammad java side of my code
I'm not sure it's correct

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, String> Green = new HashMap<>();

Map<Integer, String> white = new HashMap<>();


checkBox_TumParca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

if(checkBox_TumParca.isChecked()){

for(int i=0;i<barkodlar.size();i++){

listemiz.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

Green.put(i,"Yeşil");

white.remove(i);

}

}else{

for(int i=0;i<barkodlar.size();i++){

listemiz.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

white.put(i,"Beyaz");

Green.remove(i);

}

}

}

});





ArrayList<Integer> posit = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Integer> yesil = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Integer> beyaz = new ArrayList<>();




listemiz.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



@Override


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,


long id) {





try {

String a=Green.get(position);

if (a!="Yeşil"){

listemiz.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

Green.put(position,"Yeşil");

white.remove(position);

}

else if (a=="Yeşil"){

listemiz.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

white.put(position,"Beyaz");

Green.remove(position);

}

}catch (Exception ex){

dialog("",ex.getMessage(),false);

}




}


});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Automatically selected item element in list view**
*please refer this 2 link, I hope you getting your solution*

[This is first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468852/android-listview-the-checkbox-change-random)

[This is second link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/01/add-remove-items-to-custom-listview.html)